# Is it possible to host multiple streams at the same time in agora.io?

Tags: agora.io

i'm building an app that lets users live stream and many users could be live streaming at the same time, is that possible with agora.io? I'm using the web version with vue.js.

Answer (score 0):

Agora's Platform supports these features. In the SDK, each channel represents a live stream, which can have up to 17 broadcasters and 1m audience members.

The Agora SDKs allow developers to build apps that implement channels as needed. Within the Agora platform, users are matched by AppID and Channel name, so your app will initialize the engine with the AppID, and then join channels by passing in the channel name as a string. ([See guide on how to join/leave channel](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/join_and_leave_web_ng?platform=Web))